# How to set the text of a checkbox

Tags: docusignapi

In the end of the document, I want to show a checkbox with a prepopulated text, something like:
 [ ] By checking, I've read the whole document and agree to sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 'text' ([old documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text%20Tab.htm), [new documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/), expand the text menu at the bottom) to display your text.

In C#, it would look like this :

```
Text myText = new Text
{
    Value = "By checking, I\'ve read the whole document and agree to sign.",
    DocumentId = "123",
    PageNumber = "1"
};
```

Comment: What does it mean "expand the text menu". I use java, I can add it as text Tab. But somehow the text does not show.

Comment: By expand the text menu, I meant that to see all the details of the REST API and especially the properties of the Text tab, you need to expand the Text entry at the bottom of the new documentation link. But in the end, I believe the old one is pretty close to the new one if not the same